# What's the benefit of a Druid (or a Warrior Druid in particular) having a shield?

Tags: druid, 13th-age, shield

A  Druid (from 13 True Ways, page 38) gets +0 base AC and a -2 attack penalty for having a shield, going by the 13th age PDFs. There's an asterisk note that says:

> * Warrior druid talent choices can change shield and one-handed weapon stats.

A *Warrior Druid* in particular can choose the following for a benefit:

> You can use a shield without taking an attack penalty like other druids. (For the record, you only get the shield AC bonus while fighting in humanoid form.)

... which brings us to +0 base AC and a -0 attack penalty for having a shield! There appears to be nothing further directly affecting shields. At this point, it seems more worthwhile just sticking with a weapon and nothing else. (That's surprising, given there's another Warrior Druid benefit for using heavy one-handed melee weapons without penalty.)

Is there a particular point to a 13th Age Druid, or Warrior Druid, picking up a shield? Is the sole point to get benefits that might otherwise be attached to a Shield magic item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shield gives +1 to AC in the printed version of the book. It is most likely a peculiar typo in the pdf, as it makes much more sense to grant the ability to use a shield without penalties if it actually does something.